# Make Xcode tell the compiler to not link to any library including the standard library?

Tags: c, objective-c, compiler-construction, linker, standard-library

How can I make Xcode tell the compiler not to link?

I am making a library which may not link to anything. Where can I set in the target's properties that it must **not** link to the standard library, as I can choose `static` or `dynamic` only, there is no `not` option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have *Link With Standard Libraries* checkbox in the same section of project properties (LINK_WITH_STANDARD_LIBRARIES). Just uncheck it.

Comment: Does this option have to do with the math library? One library that I'm trying to link with my project defines log2 as a static variable, therefore the compiler complains with log2 being redefined. Unchecking this option didn't work in this case.

Comment: Technically, redefinition will be detected at compile time, so before linking. If you do not link to math library, but include its header somewhere, possibly indirectly, the compiler will still detect the problem.